# Error in my Python Code for DNA Sequencing

Tags: python

So here's a code I've been working on. I'm trying to use the str.index method for a given DNA strand, but to no avail. There's an error somewhere in this code, but I'm not sure what I had forgotten to include. If you could give me some pointers as to why this program isn't working, that would be great:

```
class dnaString (str):
    def __new__(self,s):
        return str.__new__(self,s.upper())

    def getNewStrand (self):
        return str.index("ACTG")

    def printNewStrand (self):
        print ("New DNA strand: {0}".format(str.index("ACTG")))

dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
x=dnaString(dna)
x.printNewStrand()
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error? Or just incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.index`, not `str.index`:

```
    print ("New DNA strand: {0}".format(self.index("ACTG")))
```

or better yet, fix `getNewStrand` and use it in `printNewStrand`:

```
def getNewStrand(self):
    return self.index("ACTG")

def printNewStrand(self):
    print("New DNA strand: {0}".format(self.getNewStrand()))
```

---

`str.index` is a method which requires 2 arguments:

```
>>> str.index('abc','b')
1
```

It finds the index of the first occurrence of `b` in `abc` (if there is one).

`self` is an instance of `str`. When you call a method using an instance, the instance is supplied *implicitly* as the first argument to the function. So `self.index('ACTG')` calls

```
str.index(self, 'ACTG')
```

---

`self.index('ACTG')` will raise a ValueError if `ACTG` is not in `self`. If you'd rather not raise an error, you could instead call `self.find('ACTG')`. If `ACTG` is not in `self`, `self.find` will return -1 instead of raising a ValueError. Otherwise, it behaves the same as `self.index`.

Comment: hm... I tried that, but then python says the substring isn't found

Comment: That's quite possible. It just means `ACTG` is not in `self`.